# I wonder what that would be

Tags: word-property, history, time, number-property

This is my own puzzle.

Consider the following

1. Alice begins march for peace in East Bengal along with Gandhi
2. Bentley celebrated the first Bahia Independence Day
3. Catherine saw the starting of the Great fire of Rome under Emperor Nero
4. Dorothy saw the first international soccer game: Scotland draws with England (0-0) in Glasgow

Which of the following can be true for Lumine? Why?

1. Witnessed the bombarding of Sevastopol for the first time by the French and the British during the Crimean War
2. Lost 11 days from September 3 - September 13
3. Saw the 23rd perihelion of Halley's comet
4. Died when the Imperial Japanese Navy attacked the US Pearl Harbor

Comment: Lumine is not mentioned in the first four points.  Is this intentional?

Comment: Yes. There was a minor error in calculation. I had to change the sentences. Please see the corrected one

Comment: I believe the years are 1) avargrra sbegl frira 2) rvtugrra gjragl guerr 3) fvkgl sbhe 4) rvtugrra friragl gjb / 1) rvtugrra svsgl sbhe-svir 2) friragrra svsgl gjb 3) (abg fher juvpu lrne gur ahzorevat vf vagraqrq gb fgneg sebz) 4) avargrra sbegl bar. Not that I know what to do with any of that.

Comment: The specific dates for each event, if it saves some time: rot13(Nyvpr: Wnahnel frpbaq, avargrra sbegl-frira; Oragyrl: Whyl frpbaq, rvtugrra gjragl-guerr; Pngurevar: Whyl rvtugrragu, fvkgl-sbhe; Qbebgul: Abirzore guvegvrgu, rvtugrra friragl-gjb. Bcgvbaf sbe Yhzvar: Bpgbore friragrragu, rvtugrra svsgl-sbhe; Frcgrzore frpbaq, friragrra svsgl-gjb; Wnahnel rvtugu, sbhegrra svsgl-fvk; Qrprzore friragu, avargrra sbegl-bar.). There's also a bit of meta-puzzling one can do given the edit history, but not sure that's in the spirit of solving.